# feature mobile phone tracking application

Tags: python, security, mobile

I would like to build a mobile phone tracking application for feature phones which have minimum of gprs connectivity. I would like a user to log in to the application and be able to see the location of their phone through google maps. Any resources or information will be highly appreciated. I would preferably use python.

Comment: I only know [python for Symbiam S60](https://garage.maemo.org/projects/pys60).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no way to get Python code running on that kind of mobile platform.

Try looking up JavaME and/or Brew.  Further, you will need the carrier and device maker to allow your app the get access to the phone's GPS information.  This is not a given on the low-end devices.

As a first step, most carriers have a free developer relation program.  Sign up there and you will have access to many forums with experts in the field.

Good luck.  :)

Comment: Since python cant run on such platforms. Can SMS work eg a user sends a code and the app sends a tracking code which the user enters into the app on the web and it responds by showing the user a location on google maps. how can i do that?

Comment: SMS does not have a field for location.  It would have to be an application running on the phone that read the GPS info and then crafted an SMS with the location data in the message body. (So you are back to needing Java or Brew)

Comment: That being said, many carriers do have limited support for Location Aware applications over SMS.  You will need to contact them directly.  (via their developer programs, as I mentioned.)